# Possible to change the size of rendered cards?

Tags: botframework

is it possible to change the size of these cards in Skype or any other messaging platform available via the Microsoft Bot Framework?

As you can see the text is cut off which is problematic, since it doesn't seem like it's possible to expand the card in the Skype UI.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, not without modifying the render code for Adaptive cards. The code is  open source on github: (https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards)

Answer (score 0):

As Ed said, you would have to modify the card's code itself. The cards are rendered differently depending on the channel you view them through. There is a *slightly* outdated channel inspector [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Skype/) that shows how the different card types are rendered on each channel, if they render at all (for example, adaptive cards do not work well, if at all, on Skype, and Lists look dumb on Facebook).